# Python Flask Matching Dynamic Data Points to Fixed Heading

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am building a Flask app I have a set of 5 dynamic data points that are passed to my template. These data points are passed in a list `list = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]`.

I know that the data always comes out in the same order. `1` belongs to `Heading 1`, `2`, belongs to `Heading 2`, etc..

How can I match this data with the proper heading? My initial thought was to iterate through the list

```
{% for item in list %}
     Heading 1: {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Obviously this wouldn't work at the heading doesn't iterate so they would all end up with `Heading 1` but I hope this clearly conveys what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jinja2 [`loop.index`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#for) inside the `for`-loop:

```
{% for item in list %}
    Heading {{loop.index}}: {{item}}
{% endfor %}
```

Conveniently `loop.index` starts at 1, which should work for you.

Example, give the template the following list

```
l=["first heading", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"]
```

Feed it to this:

```
{% for item in l %}
<h{{loop.index}}>{{ item }}</h{{loop.index}}>
{% endfor %}
```

The output is:

```
<h1>first heading</h1>

<h2>second</h2>

<h3>third</h3>

<h4>fourth</h4>

<h5>fifth</h5>
```

However if your list only contains integers in consecutive order, why not simply use them instead of the index?

```
{% for item in list %}
    Heading {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough. The list contains floats, I was just giving an example, and the headings are not `Heading 1`, `Heading 2` they do not follow a pattern. They are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through your comments to another previous answer, it seems like you need a dictionary instead of a list.

```
my_dictionary = { "Heading x": 1, "Heading Y":2 } #..and so on
```

Then, in your template,

```
{% for key, value in my_dict.iteritems() %}
    {{ key }} : {{ value }}
{%endfor %}
```

This will give you:

```
Heading X : 1
Heading Y : 2
```

Comment: This would work as well however I still run into the problem of how do I pair the output (a list) with the appropriate heading.

Comment: Why does your output have to be a list ? Can it be a dictionary ?